Keycloak Angular Karma Tests: Refused to frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"
currently stumbled over this problem:
I am trying to connect an angular app to keycloak (in docker).
For that I am using:
"keycloak-angular": "^15.2.1", "keycloak-js": "^22.0.5",
app.module:
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService, TranslateStore } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { OspUiModule } from './osp-ui/osp-ui.module';
import { KeycloakRealmService } from './core/keycloak-realm-service';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: KeycloakRealmService.getKeycloakBaseUrl(),
        realm: 'beutlhauser',
        clientId: 'frontend'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: false
      }
    });
}


@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // ngx-translate and the loader module
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    OspUiModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [TranslateService, TranslateStore, KeycloakRealmService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }],
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}


When executing ng serve, everything works as expected.
But when I run ng test (karma), i get this error in the console:
Refused to frame 'http://keycloak:7300/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
So why is it using iframes here? I used onLoad: 'login-required' to exactly not use iframes.
Downgrade libs
add checkLoginIframe: false
adding keycloak:7300 to CSP in keycloak realm settings itself
